# Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' on Eas Build

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I've been trying to do an Android build using eas:

```
eas build --profile=staging --platform=android
```

On local, using Android Studio it works fine but on Eas it fails.
Here's the stack trace from EAS.

```
Running './gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
Unzipping /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9-all.zip to /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs
Set executable permissions for: /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/bin/gradle
Welcome to Gradle 6.9!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - This is a small backport release.
 - Java 16 can be used to compile when used with Java toolchains
 - Dynamic versions can be used within plugin declarations
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
> Configure project :expo-file-system
WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
> Configure project :expo-structured-headers
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
> Configure project :expo
Using expo modules
  - expo-application (4.0.2)
  - expo-clipboard (2.1.1)
  - expo-constants (13.0.2)
  - expo-crypto (10.1.2)
  - expo-device (4.1.1)
  - expo-document-picker (10.1.3)
  - expo-error-recovery (3.0.5)
  - expo-file-system (13.1.3)
  - expo-firebase-analytics (6.0.1)
  - expo-firebase-core (4.1.1)
  - expo-font (10.0.5)
  - expo-json-utils (0.2.1)
  - expo-keep-awake (10.0.2)
  - expo-linear-gradient (11.0.3)
  - expo-localization (12.0.1)
  - expo-manifests (0.2.4)
  - expo-modules-core (0.6.5)
  - expo-network (4.1.1)
  - expo-notifications (0.14.1)
  - expo-permissions (13.1.1)
  - expo-secure-store (11.1.1)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.14.2)
  - expo-structured-headers (2.1.1)
  - expo-updates (0.11.6)
> Configure project :lottie-react-native
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns 
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/bundle/buildBundle.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/bundle/bundle.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
- /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at tryRequireResolve (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:157:9)
    at resolveStandardizedNameForRequrie (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:195:19)
    at sync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:224:12)
    at sync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/gensync/index.js:182:19)
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/gensync/index.js:210:24
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePlugin (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:83:17)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
[stderr] > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 2m 26s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
49 actionable tasks: 49 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
```

Comment: did you find any solution. I have the exact issue.  I upgraded expo sdk from 42 to 43. expo build is working but was build is failing with almost identical stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be different for everyone but running "./gradlew clean" locally provided more details.

For me the solution was doing the following changes on `android/gradle.properties` file:

```
-org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
+org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```